# dismissing keyboard with sender vs self._inputBox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In running my program, a basic chat app which i'm writing to learn ios, i noticed different results with:

```
[self._inputBox  resignFirstResponder];
```

vs

```
[sender  resignFirstResponder];
```

i have this ibaction:

```
- (IBAction)_sendText:(id)sender
```

which is called on hitting the send button. its also called on enter as that ibaction calls the same ibaction as the send button.

Now on the iphone which i just supported tonight ( it's a one view now i have both a view on my ipad storyboard and my ipod and wired the ipad actions to the ipod storyboard tonight) for clicking the send button which is wired to this ibaction, self.inputBox calling resignFirstResponder works but sender resignFirstResponder did not work.  I have a friend who is testing and he was the one who found it didn't work on his ipod.  I have only run it in the simulator and both worked there.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a "Send" button is connected to your `_sendText:` action and you click that button, then the button is the sender and not your text input field, therefore [`sender resignFirstResponder]` will not have the desired effect.

Comment: @LanternMike: If my answer helped, you should "accept" it by clicking on the check mark outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: @LanternMike: If an answer helped, you should ACCEPT it by clicking on the check mark, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: it says vote up requires 15 reputation points. i did earlier click hte button that this answer is useful to me.

Comment: i clicked the green check now. maybe that is what is meant :)